# Get sibling checkbox input from array of span elements

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I am trying in vein to grab a sibling checkbox item from an array of span elements with JavaScript.

I have created a function that grabs all of the span elements I require.

I am then storing the contents into a JSON object and hiding it in a hidden field. (This for something irrelevant to the question)

Here is the code:

```
var spanArray = $("#sortable span[data-attrib='attrib']");
jsonArray = [];
for (var s = 0; s < spanArray.length; s++) {
    jsonArray.push({
        "entityid": spanArray[s].getAttribute("data-entityid"),
        "entitytype": spanArray[s].getAttribute("data-entitytype")
    });
}
$("#<%= hdnData.ClientID %>").val(JSON.stringify(jsonArray));
console.log($("#<%= hdnData.ClientID %>").val());
```

This all works perfectly well. But what i also need to add more properties to my JSON object.  I need to determine the checked state of a checkbox that is a sibling of each span element in my array.

Ive tried to grab the check box whilst looping through the span array like this :

```
var chkbox = spanArray[s].siblings('input');
```

But I am getting an error

> TypeError: spanArray[s].siblings is not a function

How do I grab the check box and its checked state from the span array?

The HTML as requested:

```
<ul id="sortable" class="sortable ui-sortable">
    <li id="ctl00_MainContentPlaceHolder_ctl00_lstItems_ctrl1_liObject" class="ui-state-default">
        <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrow-4"></span>
        <span data-attrib="attrib" data-entityid="3" data-entitytype="RxdClaimDocument">PBA LOA</span>
        <span>
            <input id="chkRequired" type="checkbox">
        </span>
    </li>
    <li id="ctl00_MainContentPlaceHolder_ctl00_lstItems_ctrl2_liObject" class="ui-state-default">
        <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrow-4"></span>
        <span data-attrib="attrib" data-entityid="4" data-entitytype="RxdClaimantDocument">FOS Sig Page (PBA)</span>
        <span>
            <input id="chkRequired" type="checkbox">
        </span>
    </li>
    <li style="" id="ctl00_MainContentPlaceHolder_ctl00_lstItems_ctrl0_liObject" class="ui-state-default">
        <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrow-4"></span>
        <span data-attrib="attrib" data-entityid="2" data-entitytype="DocumentPurposeName">Pba Letter Of Claim</span>
        <span>
            <input id="chkRequired" type="checkbox">
        </span>
    </li>

    <li id="ctl00_MainContentPlaceHolder_ctl00_lstItems_ctrl3_liObject" class="ui-state-default">
        <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrow-4"></span>
        <span data-attrib="attrib" data-entityid="5" data-entitytype="RxdClaimantDocument">Photo Id</span>
        <span>
            <input id="chkRequired" type="checkbox">
        </span>
    </li>

    <li id="ctl00_MainContentPlaceHolder_ctl00_lstItems_ctrl4_liObject" class="ui-state-default">
        <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrow-4"></span>
        <span data-attrib="attrib" data-entityid="6" data-entitytype="RxdClaimantDocument">Proof of Address</span>
        <span>
            <input id="chkRequired" type="checkbox">
        </span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Use `spanArray.eq(s).next('span').find('input:checkbox')` as per your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use soemthing like

```
var spanArray = $("#sortable span[data-attrib='attrib']");

var jsonArray = spanArray.map(function () {
    var $this = $(this),
        $checked = $this.siblings('input:checkbox');
    return {
        "entityid": $this.data("entityid"),
            "entitytype": $this.data("entitytype"),
        checked: $checked.is(':checked')
    }
}).get();
```

- [.map()](https://api.jquery.com/map/)
- [siblings()](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/)

Comment: Ive used this example, but im now unable to check the check boxes

Comment: can you share the html sample

Comment: @Derek http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/tkyqzg4v/2/ - it is not a sibling.. the checkbox is a child of the next sibling element so `$checked = $this.siblings('input:checkbox')`

Answer (score 1):

As `spanArray[s]` will return you DOM element and they don't have `siblings()` method.

You should use [`$.fn.eq(index)`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/#eq-index)

> Reduce the set of matched elements to the one at the specified index

*Code*

```
spanArray.eq(s).next('span').find('input:checkbox')
```

Your code can be improved using [`$.fn.map()`](https://api.jquery.com/map/) and [`$.fn.get()`](https://api.jquery.com/get/#get2)

```
var jsonArray = $("#sortable span[data-attrib='attrib']").map(function() {
    var _this = $(this),
        _checked = _this.next('span').find('input:checkbox');
    return {
        "entityid": _this.data("entityid"),
        "entitytype": _this.data("entitytype"),
        "isChecked": _checked.is(':checked')
    }
}).get();
```

Comment: Do you mean `eq` not `ep`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var chkbox = $(spanArray[s]).siblings('input');
```